# Initialize class variable by passing a reference to it

Tags: c++, reference

I have a quite interesting and funny C++ exercise:

This the imposed main:

```
int main(void)
{
    Exam e = Exam(&Exam::cheat);
    e.kobayashiMaru = &Exam::start;
    (e.*e.kobayashiMaru)(3);
    Exam::cheat = true;
    if (e.isCheating())
        (e.*e.kobayashiMaru)(4);
    return (0);
}
```

And this is the asked output:

```
[The exam is starting]
3 Klingon vessels appeared out of nowhere.
You lost again.
[The exam is starting]
4 Klingon vessels appeared out of nowhere.
Win !
```

You now need to create the `Exam` class to get the correct output.
Here is what I've done:

```
class Exam
{
public:

    Exam(bool *_cheat);

    typedef void (Exam::*func)(int);
    void            start(int);
    bool                       isCheating();
    static bool               cheat;
    func                       kobayashiMaru;
};
```

I encounter problems with the `Exam(&Exam::cheat)` thing. What I understand so far is that `Exam` is taking the address of it's own `cheat` variable. When entering the `Exam`'s constructor `cheat` is uninitialized. So for me I would initialize it here with `false`.

```
Exam::Exam(bool * _cheat)
{
   *_cheat = false;
}
```

But by doing this I get a multiple definition with `Exam(&Exam::cheat)`. I'm not sure about my reflection, can maybe someone enlighten me on what's really happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
static bool cheat;
```

to:

```
bool cheat;
```

inside your `Exam` class to allow every new object handle its own `cheat` variable with its own value.

Constructor will initialize your `cheat` variable by given value while you creating new object with constructor like this:

```
Exam::Exam(bool isCheating)
{
   this->cheat = isCheating;
}
```

Or if you want to initialize `cheat` variable as false/true by default you can make constructor like this:

```
Exam::Exam()
{
   cheat = false;
   //or cheat = true;
}
```

You can handle multiple constructors too.

Now to create new object from `Exam` class use:

```
Exam *exam1 = new Exam(true); //Will initialize cheat as false
Exam *exam2 = new Exam(false); //Will initialize cheat variable as true
```

Then access your methods inside exam1 and exam2 object like this:

```
exam1->methodName(1243);
exam2->secondMethodName(true);
exam2->thirdMethodName();
exam3->addFriend(&exam1);
```

Those ones are just examples.

Hope I understood your problem. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer skprime. But actually the goal is doing the exercice with the imposed main

Comment: @Robin I don't understand two things. 1. Why are you creating new object like this: Exam e = Exam(&Exam::cheat); instead of Exam* e = new Exam(Exam::cheat); 2. Method start(); inside your class is non-static, you are calling it like a static function here: Exam::start(); For me that's really strange main. Yeah sure I can achieve this output but with another main "structure".

Comment: Because it is an **imposed** main. I didnt make it and i cant change it. All the difficulty of the exercice is here : generate the asked output with the given main. Changing the main have no interest here, i know how to create a class and use it...

Comment: Who created that strange main? :P

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues (described in comments below)

```
class Exam
{
public:

    // If cheat is supposed to be a member variable assigned to each instance, passing a pointer to itself is silly and unnecessary
    // If cheat is supposed to be shared between all instances of exam, passing a pointer to itself is silly and unnecessary
    Exam(bool *_cheat);
    static bool               cheat;


    // these two declarations are unnecessary.  They do nothing but add complexity where it is not needed
    typedef void (Exam::*func)(int); 
    func                       kobayashiMaru;

    void            start(int);
    bool                       isCheating();
};
```

> I encounter problems with the Exam(&Exam::cheat) thing. What I
>   understand so far is that Exam is taking the address of it's own cheat
>   variable. When entering the Exam's constructor cheat is uninitialized.
>   So for me I would initialize it here with false.

Static variables are initialized before the creating of the first instance of a class.  The problem you have is two-fold:  1) you haven't initialized your static member variable, 2) you aren't treating it as a static member variable.

Declaring a variable as `static` means it will be shared between all instances of the class (e.g. there will be 1 memory location for `cheat`).  Unless you want everyone taking the `Exam` to cheat as soon as 1 person cheats, this is not likely what you want.

To fix it, you would want your `Exam` class to look more like this:

```
class Exam
{
public:
    Exam(bool cheat) : m_cheat(cheat) {}

    // don't expose member variables directly - use accessor functions
    void setCheating(bool cheat) { m_cheat = cheat; }
    bool isCheating() const { return m_cheat; }

    void start(int);
private:
    bool               m_cheat;
};
```

The corresponding changes to your `main` function

```
int main(void)
{
    Exam e(false);
    e.start(3);
    e.setCheating(true);
    if (e.isCheating())
        e.start(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cant change the main... You must do the exercice with the given main... I think i should better delete my post